# Not able to Decrypt string using RSA.rb: RSA Encryption for Ruby

Tags: ruby, rsa, encryption

I have to encrypt a particular field value and store in DB. I have used RSA Encryption for Ruby. I was able to encrypt and save it, but then while decrypting it back, i am facing problem. What i have done is as follows,

```
key_pair = RSA::KeyPair.generate(512)
```

Stored key_pair in separate column.

```
ciphertext = key_pair.encrypt("Hello, world!")
```

Stored ciphertext in another column in same table.

While decrypting, i fetched the key_pair value from database and applied decrypting function

```
plaintext = key_pair.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

This step throws error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `decrypt' for <String:0xa431b88>
```

because "key_pair" is not an instance of "RSA::KeyPair".

When i try to decrypt the stored value, i fetch key_pair value from database and then apply decrypt method on it. So the key_pair value has String class. I need a way to solve. Please guide me.

Comment: you've receive a key pair from db but not the object that is an instance of RSA::KeyPair and that has a `decrypt` method

Answer (score 0):

Before decrypt, try:

```
# get persisted value from DB; then
key_pair = RSA::KeyPair.new(your private key, your public key)

# and then decrypt
plaintext = key_pair.decrypt(ciphertext)
```